# What is dgrant_type=client_credentials in this CURL command?

Tags: curl, post

`curl https://api.app.com/oauthpreview/token --user key:secret -XPOST -dgrant_type=client_credentials`

---

What is the `dgrant_type=client_credentials`? I'm going to rewrite this example curl command into Ruby code using an http client.

Answer (score 1):

(first: `-X POST` should not be used when you use `-d`, it is already implied)

`-d` specifies the content to send in the HTTP request body. This command will thus send `grant_type=client_credentials` in the body.

Add `--trace-ascii dump` when you invoke the command and inspect the `dump` file afterwards to see exactly what curl sent and received.